# How to write nested serializer and generic views for reverse and forward relation ships i.e foreign key relationships

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Here's models.py

```
Class Customer(models.Model):
    ...

Class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    customer =  models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Class Component1(models.Model):
    ...
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Class Component2(models.Model):
    ...
    project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here's the serializers.py

```
class ProjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer(many=True)
    component1 = Component1Serializer()
    component2 = Component2Serializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Project
```

and my views.py

```
class ProjectList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

The view is acting as if it is a non-nested serializer.
How to display the whole contents of the serializer?

> Edit 1: If I use depth = 1 in meta class under serializer, the forward relation, i.e. customer will show but not the reverse relationship fields.

If I do print(repr(ProjectList())) , It is displaying exactly the format I want, but the view is unable to provide it

I am new to this platform, please comment if I can improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally understood what I was doing wrong.

```
class ProjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer()
    component1_set = Component1Serializer(many=True) #observe the modelname_set instead 
    component2_set = Component2Serializer(many=True) # of modelname/arbitrary name, applicable for reverse relationships.
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        depth = 1 # this is for the forward relationship (i.e. Customer over here)
```

If you want to set an arbitrary name, use

```
...
somename = Component1Serializer(many=True ,source = 'modelname_set')
...
```

Also keep many=True, because it is one to many relationship in a reverse manner.
If you don't want to use depth for forward relations,
simply use

```
modelname = ModelSerializer()
# i.e.
customer = CustomerSerializer()
```

There will be no change in views, but it would be easier to use ModelViewSet and a router configuration
hence views.py

```
class ProjectListViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectListSerializer
```

If your queryset needs to be dynamic for some reason, try using
`queryset = Project.objects.all().prefetch_related()`